# Trying to find out how to deducing formulas in FCM algorithm

Tags: algorithms, cluster

FCM algorithm or Fuzzy C-Means Algorithm is a clustering algorithm with a matrix with values between 0 to 1 to representing the membership function as membership function in K-means 0-1 approach.

When the distance function in FCM algorithm is the Euclidean distance, the objetive function to minimize is:

[image]

with constrains:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} u_{ij} = 1 \ \forall j=1, \cdots, n$$

The authors of algorithm deduce:

[image]
[image]

With:

- $n$ : # elements to clustering (data)
- $\alpha$ : a constant
- $k$ : # of centroids at beginning
- $D_{\text{euc}}(x_i, \mu_j)$: euclidean distance of j-centroid to i-element of data
- $u_{ij}$ element i-j of membership matrix $u\in M_{n\times k}$
- $x_i$: vectors m-dimensional

If I would like to modify the function distance, how this change affects the outcomes of minimize ? (red dashed boxes).

To find out the how. I was trying to apply multiplier's Lagrange method to $J_\alpha$ with original conditions to deduce original formulas (red dashed boxes), without successful.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. Not only is it lazy, it also makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and maths (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!